# MongoDB product collectiiona and syntax error in defining a collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to learn MongoDB and tried to do the collection:

```
{
  "type": "Audio Album",
  "title": "A Love Supreme",
  "description": "by John Coltrane",
  "shipping": {
    "weight": 6,
    "dimensions": [{
      "width": 10,
      "height": 10,
      "depth": 1
    }]
  },
  "pricing": [{
    "list": 1200,
    "retail": 1100,
    "savings": 100,
    "pct_savings": 8
  }],
  "details": {
    "title": "A Love Supreme [Original Recording Reissued]",
    "artist": "John Coltrane",
    "genre": "Jazz",
    "tracks": ["", "", "", ""]
  }
}
```

However, https://mongoplayground.net/p/AndUCdMxqLq shows that I have a syntax error and I have problems finding it. Is there anybody that will be able to help? Thank you

Comment: Try this: [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/efHKPYFnVVC); there must have been some typing mistake. I think you can use `mongo` shell, _or_ MongoDB Compass and try your queries (since you are saying that you are learning).